# Bilinear interpolation implementation

Tags: matlab, linear-interpolation

I am trying to implement a bilinear interpolation function, but for some reason it doesn't work.
this is my function:

```
    function [g] = imgscale(data)

    a = data;
    [row col d] = size(a);  %3 dimentional array
    zoom=3;                 %zooming factor
    zr=zoom*row;
    zc=zoom*col;

    for i=1:zr

        x=i/zoom;

        x1=floor(x);
        x2=ceil(x);
        if x1==0
            x1=1;
        end

        for j=1:zc

            y=j/zoom;

            y1=floor(y);
            y2=ceil(y);
            if y1==0
                y1=1;
            end

            BL=a(x1,y1,:);
            TL=a(x1,y2,:);
            BR=a(x2,y1,:);
            TR=a(x2,y2,:);           

            R1=((x2-x)/(x2-x1))*BR+((x-x1)/(x2-x1))*BL;
            R2=((x2-x)/(x2-x1))*TR+((x-x1)/(x2-x1))*TL;
            P=((y2-y)/(y2-y1))*R1+((y-y1)/(y2-y1))*R2;
            im_zoom(i,j,:)=p;

        end
    end
g = im_zoom;
```

When it becomes enlarge, there are black rows and cols in the image.
How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are several errors in your code, both in logic and understanding of the algorithm as well as at least one typo, but I will restrict myself to solving the immediate problem of black lines in the image.

What happens in your code when

> x == x1 == x2?

Substituting `x` for `x1` and `x2` in `R1` we get

```
R1=((x-x)/(x-x))*BR+((x-x)/(x-x))*BL;
or
R1=(0/0)*BR+(0/0)*BL
```

I'm surprised you're not getting divide by zero warnings. One way to avoid this (not necessarily the best way) is to put a simple check around your calculations of `R1`, `R2` and `P`:

```
if x == x1 % this implies x == x2 as well
    R1=BR; % same as R1=BL
    R2=TR; % same as R1=TL
else
    % normal calculations for R1 & R2
end
if y == y1
    P=R1;
else
    % normal calculation for P
end
```

I didn't explicitly include the calculations for `R1`, `R2` and `P` here because this where another of the errors creeps in and I didn't want to post incorrect code as part of a solution. Fixing this error will also allow a cleaner, more elegant solution to the current problem.

Other problems I've noticed so far are:
 - Your attempt to keep `x1` and `y1` from being zero seems a bit off. You need to consider what behavior you expect at the extremes of the value range (say, the first four and last four pixels of a row).
 - You shouldn't use `i` and `j` as loop variables since Matlab already defines these as the imaginary units.
 - Your weights for calculating the colors of an interpolated pixel are incorrect. Think about how much contribution the color on the left should have if the pixel is closer to the left than to the right.
 - Once your weight calculations are correct, they can be simplified by noticing that `x2 - x1` is always either zero or one for the case of increasing the image size.
 - I assume the last line of the loop has a typo and there should be a capital `P` in `im_zoom(i,j,:)=P;`